# How to use map function get

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a map of strings to integers. I would like to check if the map has a certain string and if so modify the integer value to which it's mapped to.

```
Map <String, Integer> m= new SortedMap <String,Integer>();
Map <String, Integer> m2 = new SortedMap<StringInteger>();
//do some stuff
Iterator <String,Integer>  i = m2.iterator();
//add some values into the first map first map

    while (i.hasNext()){
       String temp =  i.next();
      int found = m.get(temp);
     if ( found != null) {//this is giving me a syntax error , something about how ints 
                                                               can't be null , do I just compare it to zero

    //process value that temp maps to 
       averages.put(temp, val); //
    }
```

}

Also when I put in the key during the second loop, will it remove the first key, and put in another key with the newly process value.

Comment: also try to use map.containsKey(keyValue); there is no need for extra loops.

Comment: if I use map.contains, Wouldn't I still need to use get to get the value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change `int` to `Integer`:

```
Integer found = m.get(temp);
```

'int' is a primitive and cannot be compared to null.

Map keys are unique, so if you put the same key twice it will be replaced

Comment: Great, that's just the answer I needed. Also if I wanted to traverse the map and increment all of the values. Would I have to do found = m.get(temp) , m.put(temp, ++found found); Or is there a more efficient way when you loop through the whole map and update every entry

Comment: Maybe add something about auto (un)boxing?

Comment: Integers are immutable so you indeed need to replace the value in your map with the increased value like you mention. You could work around this by using a custom class as map value which has the int as a field. Then once you have the reference to your value you can just increase the field value withou the need to put it in the map again.

Answer (score 2):

It looks what you are trying to do can be done with putAll.

```
Map<String, Integer> both = ...
both.putAll(m1);
both.putAll(m2);
```

This will have all the values from m2 and any values only in m1.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this for the adding via reference to mutable custom class:

```
Map<String, MyValue> myMap = new HashMap<String, MyValue>();
(...)
MyValue value = myMap.get(temp);
value.inc();

(...)

public class MyValue {
    private int value;
    public int get() {
        return value;
    }
    public void set(int newValue) {
        this.value = newValue;
    }
    public void inc() {
        value++;
    }
}
```

EDIT: to inc all values using above approach:

```
for(MyValue value : myMap.values()) {
    value.inc();
}
```

Without the MyValue wrapper:

```
for(String key : m.keySet()) {
    Integer value = m.get(key);
    m.put(key, value + 1);
}
```

See [Map interface API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Comment: This isn't part of the original question. I now want to loop through the entire map and increment each value. Is there a way I can get each value sequentially

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. How come I couldn't find at the java map library page